# Converting string to a date but date not formatted properly

Tags: sql

I am having issues with converting a string into a date. The issue is that the format of the string does not easily convert to a date. For example, all the dates are set up like APR-19, or JAN-21. I am not sure how to properly cast this. Here is the SQL I am using.

```
Select*
 to_date(wbr_global.gl_ap_details,period_name,'MON-YY')
 from wbr_global.gl_ap_details
 where wbr_global.gl_ap_details.ledger_name = 'Amazon.com, Inc.'
 and cost_center in ('1168','1172','1092','1153','1257','1093','1705')
```

[image]

Comment: and your question is? APR-19 can be 01.04.2019, 12.04.2019,30.04.2019 or something other

Comment: @Sergey . . . You left out April 19, 2020.

Comment: Thank  you for your response, I am new to SQL and trying to figure out the line of code I need to convert the string to a date. The APR-19 is April 2019. The string includes the month and current year and has no days of the month. This is from a GL so it only has the periods.

Comment: before thinking about line of code, please think about what means APR-19

Comment: Yes, that means April 2019. That is an accounting period in our GL since we post expenses to the monthly period.

Comment: Perfect. Unfortunately, April 2019 can not be converted into date,because April consists of 30 days. What of them do you prefer?

Comment: The first day of the month would work so I would be fine if it were 4-1-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PostgreSQL it is easy:

```sql
SELECT to_date('APR-19', 'MON-YY');
```

returns 2019-04-01

```sql
SELECT to_date('JAN-21', 'MON-YY');
```

returns 2021-01-01

Comment: Thank you another issue is that I have dates in the GL going back all the way to 2000. Is there a way to convert the entire column without having to convert each unique date?

Comment: yes ```SELECT to_date(thecolumn, 'MON-YY') FROM ...```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it did not work, I updated the query i used in the original post.

Comment: 1. in updated question there is error in ```,period_name``` must be ```.period_name``` 2. and need coma after ```*```